# Fetch data from API in Node.js and send to Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

I am trying to fetch data from an API in Nodejs and then send the data to Reactjs. I can't directly fetch data in Reactjs as I need to provide the API key so for this, I am using Nodejs. I am using Axios to fetch the data. The problem is that since Axios sends the data only after it has completely fetched all the data, it takes more than 3 4 seconds to display the data which is not very good. I want to know how can I display data after every interval or as soon as Axios fetches some data, keep displaying that and loading the rest part simultaneously. My code at the backend part is

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/getdata', function (req, res) {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await axios(`${APIurl}?${APIKey}`)
        res.send(data.data);
    }
    fetchData();
})

app.listen(5000);
```

The code for the Reactjs part is like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
const Projects = () => {
    const [data, updateData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/getdata')
            .then(res => updateData(res.data))
            .catch(error => console.log("Error"))
    }, [])
   
    return (
            {data.map(project => (
                 <div key={project["id"]}>
                      <div>{project["name"]}</div>
                 </div>
             ))}
    )
}

export default Projects
```

So how can I send data from backend code so that it displays data after every some particular interval?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use case for [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or maybe [WebSocketStream](http://WebSocketStream:%20integrating%20streams%20with%20the%20WebSocket%20API%20by%20@tomayac%20https://web.dev/websocketstream/) API.

The implementation details will depend greatly on whether you want to implement any of these yourself or if you want to use some library/service (for instance, [socket.io](https://socket.io/)) and which of these 2 APIs suits best to your project.